# Software that shows the internet traffic in the system tray?

Tags: windows, internet

I'm looking for software that shows the internet traffic in the system tray ?
As Everest show the CPU Temperature there, is there any software to do that with the internet traffic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Perfgraph](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Perfgraph.shtml)** – a hardware and **bandwidth monitoring tool** for Windows. Unlike other monitoring applications, Perfgraph can embed graphs displaying the status of various hardware components right on the **Windows taskbar**.

[image]

ok, it's **not** the system tray but close! :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[DU Meter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about) can do that, and more... It can show a floating window, can integrate into a Windows taskbar and has a Sidebar Gadget. Many display styles are available, can discriminate between Internet and LAN traffic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) is a free, lightweight bandwidth monitor that offers a ton of options from customization to graphing to reporting. Current speeds available at any time in the system tray on mouseover, or display a small graph at all times in the taskbar.

Comment: It optionally also displays the current speeds (upload and download) at all times in the graph window, so you don't have to mouseover but can just glance at it. I love this program. (And yes, I am commenting on a 6 year old thread, but it is still relevant).

Answer (score 1):

[**Bitmeter II**](http://codebox.org.uk/controller?page=bitmeter2) can do this, amongst a lot of other features:

> Animated System Tray icon shows upload
>   and download speeds

Comment: Thank you, but Bitmeter only shows a little animated icon. I want one that shows the exact speed :) If that's not too much..

Comment: Isn't the tray icon a bit small to display the exact speed? It's OK for a temperature (2 digits), but a network speed???

Answer (score 1):

[NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer) can do that, and unlike all the other monitoring tools it can also control the traffic, say set limits, priorities or even block an app when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), but remember to run it in administrator mode, and choose which system tray icons to show.

[image]